# How to get an array or a list of y axis data from the curve item

Tags: c#, arrays, copy, zedgraph

I have a list item(myList) on the Zedgraph,

```
PointPairList myList = new PointPairList();
```

myList has some values in it, now I want to copy just the y values alone into a new array.

My Trails:

```
myList.toArray(); // Seems to return a complete set of pointpair list
myList.GetRange(); // Gets a range of pointPair list
```

I'm looking to find a way, to copy just the y Data.

Thanks in advance....:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
double[] yvalues = myList.Select(p => p.Y).ToArray();
```

For this you need to include `System.Linq` namespace this way

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Select` to get only the Y coordinate.

```
var result = myList.Select(pointPair => pointPair.Y).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for the solution & as both the answers are same(Nikhil),Sorry that I can only be able accept one answer.